# Connect GeoServer WMS data to Leaflet.js

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms

I have WMS Layer in GeoServer, I've made it following the walk through tutorial in https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog585/node/701

I'm confused on how to connect my WMS to leaflet.js.

Comment: did you look at [lesson 6](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog585/node/765)?

Answer (score 1):

You can add it through **L.tilelayer.wms** method of Leaflet

```
var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('https://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/ows?', {
    layers: 'ne:ne'
}).addTo(map);
```

Here are more details that you can follow

https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html